# Semantics of E and A operators in CTL*

Tags: temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic

I'm referring to a [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540415237) where E and A were defined in text as follows

> The formula $A \phi$ states that all the executions out of the current state satisfy property $\phi$ whereas $E\phi$ states that from the current state, there exists and execution satisfying $\phi$

And formally, they were defined as

> $\sigma, i \models E\phi $ iff there exists as $\sigma'$ such that $\sigma(0)\ldots\sigma(i) = \sigma'(0)\ldots\sigma'(i)$ and $\sigma', i \models phi$
>   $\sigma, i \models A\phi $ iff for all $\sigma'$ such that $\sigma(0)\ldots\sigma(i) = \sigma'(0)\ldots\sigma'(i)$, we have $\sigma', i \models phi$

$\sigma(i)$ was previously defined to be the ith state of an execution $\sigma$.

Here's where my confusion lies. Doesn't $\sigma(0)\ldots\sigma(i) = \sigma'(0)\ldots\sigma'(i)$ imply that the executions $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ have both the same start and end state, therefore $\sigma', i \models \phi$ is same as $\sigma, i \models \phi$? That seems to be wrong.

Comment: For those that do not have access to the full book, can you clarify which logic the definition is about? The question is tagged with "linear-temporal-logic", but the definition looks more like a branching-time logic to me. From the preview of your book, it seems the chapter on "Temporal Logic" deals with CTL*.

Comment: It's for CTL*, sorry about the confusion. Edited.

Comment: I've added CTL* to the title.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means that $\sigma,\sigma$ should share the same prefix up to position $i$.
Then the quantification ranges over all possible extensions of this prefix from state $\sigma(i) = \sigma(i)'$.

Answer (score -1):

I think you misinterpret the expression
$$\sigma(0) \cdots \sigma(i) = \sigma'(0) \cdots \sigma'(i')$$
and I agree that it is written in an unintuitive way.

The author means that $\sigma(i) = \sigma'(0)$ and that the final path is
$$\sigma(0) \cdots \sigma(i) \; \sigma'(0) \cdots \sigma'(i').$$

The equality ensures that the path $\sigma'$ *starts* where $\sigma$ ends.

Are you sure there isn't a prime on the $i$?